# Why does Perl complain about unmatched bracket within a \Q..\E regex section?

Tags: regex, perl

I have a regex in a variable, that includes a substring inside `\Q...\E` containing an opening bracket. I'm expecting that `[` would be interpreted like a vanilla character by the parser since it's inside a `\Q...\E` section.

This seems to be the case when the regex comes as a literal in the program, but the parser fails on it when it comes in a variable.

Here's a simplified example.

This works:

```
$r = qr/\Qa[b\E\d+/;
if ("a[b1" =~ $r) { print "match\n"; }
```

This fails:

```
$v='\Qa[b\E\d+';
$r=qr/$v/;
```

It dies at line 2 with

> Unmatched [ in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/\Qa[ <-- HERE b\E\d+/

Why would Perl reject this? And only when interpolated from a variable and not inline with the same regex?

I can't see anything explaining it in the FAQ's [How do I match a regular expression that's in a variable?](http://learn.perl.org/faq/perlfaq6.html#How-do-I-match-a-regular-expression-thats-in-a-variable-) or perlop's [Regexp Quote-Like Operators](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators).

This is with Perl 5.14.2 (Ubuntu 12.04) if the version matters, with default settings.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`\Q` has nothing to do with regular expressions. When the regex engine sees `\Q`, it doesn't recognize it, spits out a warning, and treats it like `\\Q`.

```
>perl -we"$re='\Qa'; qr/$re/
Unrecognized escape \Q passed through in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/\Q <-- HERE a/ at -e line 1.
```

Like interpolation, `\Q` is recognized by double-quoted string literals and similar. Like interpolation, it's gotta be part of a literal (Perl code) to work.

```
>perl -E"$pat=q{\Q!}; say qr/$pat/"
(?^u:\Q!)

>perl -E"$pat=qq{\Q!}; say qr/$pat/"
(?^u:\!)

>perl -E"$x='!'; $pat=q{$x}; say qr/$pat/"
(?^u:$x)

>perl -E"$x='!'; $pat=qq{$x}; say qr/$pat/"
(?^u:!)
```

Solutions:

- `$v="\Qa[b\E\\d+";`
- `$v=qr/\Qa[b\E\d+/;`
- `$v=quotemeta('a[b').'\d+';`

Comment: What I understand from this answer is that the regex I'm trying to process is wrong. I can't change it, it comes in a variable to my code. The premise of my question was that `\Q..\E` was a regex syntax construct. Since it's wrong to begin with, the rest of the question does not make sense. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @Daniel Vérité, Exactement.

Answer (score 3):

A Perl regular expression is first evaluated as if it was a simple double-quoted string. Any embedded variables are interpolated, and escape sequences that *don't* originate from interpolated variables are processed. This is the point when special operators like `\L`, `\U` and `\Q...\E` are acted on.

The processing stops there in double-quoted strings, but in regular expressions the string is then *compiled*.

In your example you have

```
$v = '\Qa[b\E\d+';
```

and because you have used single quotes, this string isn't changed at all.

You then interpolate it into a regular expression with

```
$r = qr/$v/;
```

but, because escape sequences *inside* interpolated variables are untouched, the string is passed as it is to the regex compiler, which reports that the expression is invalid because it contains an unmatched an unescaped open bracket. If you remove that bracket you still get an error; this time it is `Unrecognized escape \Q passed through in regex` showing that the `\Q...\E` hasn't been processed and appears as literals.

What *would* work is to change your assignment to `$v` to use double quotes instead, like this

```
my $v = "\Qa[b\E\\d+";
```

The backslash on `\d` has to be doubled up otherwise is would just vanish. Now the `\Q...\E` has been acted on, and `$v` is equal to `a\[b\d+`. Compiling this as a regex works fine.

Comment: @ikegami: You're right, but your code doesn't demonstrate it because escape sequences inside variables are untouched anyway. This `perl -E"say for qr/\t/, qr/\x09/, qr/\n/, qr/\x0A/"` does though, and I'm surprised because it means the double-quote processing for regexes is different from that for standard strings. (`"\t" eq "\x09"` but `qr/\t/ ne qr/\x09/`)

Comment: If you're gonna make the regex engine can understand stuff like `\t`, you might as well leave `\t` as is for readability.

Comment: OTOH, `\N{...}` gets converted to `\N{U+...}` in case you use user-defined names. `perl -Mcharnames=:full -E"say qr/\N{LATIN SMALL LETTER E WITH ACUTE}/"`

Answer (score 2):

The \Q and \E metacharacters are interpreted at the time the regex is parsed. They are not part of the regular expression itself. If \Q and \E appear inside a regex literal, they tell the parser to ignore characters that normally have special meaning inside regular expressions, including brackets. If \Q and \E appear in a single-quotes as part of a variable assignment, they are treated as literal strings. When this variable is then used inside a regex, the literal values become part of the regular expression. The backslashes are interpreted as escapes, so \Q matches a literal Q, and \E matches a literal E.

To see this, try compiling the regex and then printing it:

```
$v=qr/\Qa[b\E\d+/;
print "$v\n";
```

The output is:

```
(?-xism:a\[b\d+)
```

Note that the \Q and \E are gone, and the bracket has been escaped. If you assign a string that contains \Q and \E seperately inside single quotes:

```
$v='ab\Qcd\Eef';
$r=qr/$v/;
print "$r\n";
```

You get:

```
(?-xism:ab\Qcd\Eef)
```

This regex actually matches "abQcdEef":

```
$v='ab\Qcd\Eef';
$r=qr/$v/;
if("abQcdEef" =~ /$r/) {print "matches\n"} else {print "no match\n"}
```

result:

```
matches
```